# How can I make a select with a track by option save the selected object in the model in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I have this select, populated using ng-options:

```
<select name="userable" class="form-control"
  ng-options="u.name group by u.type for u in userables track by u.name"
  ng-model="user.userable" required>
```

The options I use to populate the select are somewhat like this:

```
$scope.userables = [{ id: 1, name: 'Userable 1' }, { id: 2, name: 'Userable 2' }, ... }];
```

The `user` object I get from the API returns a string with the userable name only, so I added the `track by u.name`, to tell Angular to auto-select the userable for me, once they're loaded. So far, so good.

The problem I have is a strange behavior of Angular. When I select an option, manually, it sets `user.userable` to an object like `{ id: 1, name: 'Userable 1' }`. However, when the page is fresh-loaded, Angular updates the select, but it doesn't update the model, so it remains the same string I got from the API, `'Userable 1'`.

Is there any way to make this work? I hate writing unnecessary code.

Please request more info if needed, I'm not sure I was clear enough.

Comment: Is your description of `userables` correct? It looks like you missed a opening and closing curly brace in there. Otherwise, it looks like a poorly created object, which could be an issue.

Comment: Sorry, it was wrong. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

Look like a weird behavior of ng-select, you need to manually `tell` what should be value for options in `ng-options`:

```
ng-options="u.name as u.name group by u.type for u in userables"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/s6XqXhQHseqbu70f1HOR?p=preview

//also I removed 'track by' because it's not recommended to use it with `as`: [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

Comment: That behavior is exactly what I want, but I want the object to go to the model instead of just the string. I know I could search for the correct user in my controller, but as I said, I hate writing unneeded code :(

Comment: Also, nice thing you pointed out about the track by and select as working together. Didn't know that.

Comment: hm, looks like I was totally wrong. is this what you wanted? http://plnkr.co/edit/OsSpXejDZxi5kNgVGZi1?p=preview

Comment: No, but the way you proposed before works, I just have to find the element by its name after. But the problem is, I can't make it work in my environment! I think it's something to do with XHR requests... Still debugging to see what's really going on though.

Comment: It's definitely a bug with the XHR requests. When the userables list is loaded first, it works as expected. If not, it doesn't select the option in the select. Now what? hahaha